# HAML markup generation question

Tags: html, haml

How should I generate such HTML with HAML?

```
Hello <span class="someclass">John</span>, you are welcome!
```

Comment: It's probably worth reviewing [this blog post](http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/) and reconsidering how to do this sort of markup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hello
= succeed "," do
  %span.someclass John
you are welcome!
```

You can use http://html2haml.heroku.com to convert